# Dynamically create Instance fields for a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically-created list of strings called 'variables'. I need to use these strings as the instance variables for an array of JavaScript objects.

```
var objectsArr  = [];
function obj(){};

for (var i=0; i<someNumberOfObjects; i++ ) {
    ...
    objectsArr[i] = new Object();           


    for (var j=0; j<variables.length; j++) {
        objectArr[i].b = 'something';  //<--this works, but...
        //objectArr[i].variables[j] = 'something';  //<---this is what I want to do.
    }       
}
```

The commented-out line shows what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the bracket syntax to manipulate the property by name:

```
objectArr[i][variables[j]] = 'something';
```

In other words, get the object from `objectArr` at index `i` then find the field with name `variables[j]` and set the value of that field to `'something'`.

In general terms, given object `o`:

```
var o = {};
```

You can set the property by name:

```
o['propertyName'] = 'value';
```

And access it in the usual way:

```
alert(o.propertyName);
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks you for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation. This will get it done:

```
var objectsArr = [], ii, jj;

function Obj() {}

for(ii = 0; ii < someNumberOfObjects; ii += 1) {
    objectsArr[ii] = new Obj();            

    for (jj = 0; jj < variables.length; jj += 1) {
        objectArr[ii][variables[jj]] = 'something';
    }       
}
```

A couple of additional notes:

- Javascript doesn't have block scope, so you must have two separate loop variables.
- By convention, constructor functions like `Obj` should begin with a capital letter to signify that they ought to be used with the `new` keyword. In this case though, unless you need the objects to have a non-Object prototype, you could just use a plain object literal (`objectsArr[ii] = {};`).